# Шифрование паролей SQLite в Qt

Tags: qt

в Sqlite есть таблица с полями логина и пароля, нужно зашифровать пароли и выводить в Qt в зашифрованном виде или в незашифрованном. Подскажите, есть ли в Qt класс, который работает с шифрованием.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/193742/

Comment: Во-первых, пароли принято хранить в виде хешей. Во-вторых, не забудьте про соль.